# glError returns INVALID_OPERATION for glUniform*

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

im calling glUniformMatrix4fv & glUniform4f and on both i get an error of INVALID_OPERATION.
glGetUniformLocation returns 0 for both mvp and color for reasons i havent figured out.

the program is valid.

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

Shader* shader = Root::getInstance()->getRenderSystem()->getShader("Test");
shader->bind();

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

kmMat4 mvp;
kmMat4 mv;
kmMat4Multiply(&mv, &model, &view);
kmMat4Multiply(&mvp, &perspective, &mv);

GLint uMvp = shader->getUniformLocation("mvp");
LOG("%i", uMvp);

glUniformMatrix4fv(uMvp, 1, GL_FALSE, mvp.mat);
checkGlErro("uniform matrix");

GLint uColor = shader->getUniformLocation("color");
LOG("%i", uColor);

glUniform4f(uColor, 0, 0, 1, 1);
checkGlErro("uniform");

glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
shader->unbind();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

shaders:

```
const std::string testShader_vert =
"uniform mat4 mvp; \n"
"attribute vec4 position; \n"
"void main() { \n"
"   gl_Position = mvp * position; \n"
"}";


const std::string testShader_frag =
"precision mediump float; \n"
"uniform vec4 color; \n"
"void main() { \n"
"   gl_FragColor = color; \n"
"}";
```

Comment: Your class called "Shader" abstracts a GLSL program... I would consider renaming it. Shaders are what you call the individual stages, and the entire thing is called a program. I know it sounds pedantic, but this `shader->getUniformLocation("color");` rubs me the wrong way. Uniforms are a per-program state, this makes me think you are trying to query the uniform location from an individual shader.

Comment: It would be really helpful if we could see the code for your `Shader` class (and agree with Andon M. Coleman on that it is not a good name). Besides that, it is not 100% clear what GL calls actually generate the errors you see, e.g. it could be the `glGetUniformLocation()` as well (like when you are not passing the name of a correctly linked _program_ object), which would also explain the location values you get.